# Minimum amount of image slices - CNN

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, conv-neural-network

The images of my dataset exceed the maximum input for my CNN. This means I need to slice my images in parts to feed to the CNN. The most simple method is like this, resulting in 4 sliced images, where 2 do not contain any labels:

[image: Not optimal solution]

The slices are marked by the dotted line.

I was wondering if there was an algorithm that finds the optimal slices to get a minimum amount of sliced images while still including all labels. Like in this example, the minimum slice amount of slices is 1:

[image: Optimal solution]

Is there any algorithm implemented in Python that does something like this?